# Comparing two arrays and created new array with different values PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

I have two arrays with following structure:

```
$arr1 = array( array( name => "name1", 
              qty => '1'    
                    ),
           array( name => "name2", 
              qty => '2'    
                    )

             );

$arr2 = array( array( name => "name1", 
              qty => '1'    
                    ),
           array( name => "name2", 
              qty => '1'    
                    )

             );
```

Resultat:

```
$arr3 = array( array( name => "name2", 
              qty => '1'    
                    )

             );
```

$arr3 getting different value from arr2 !

**Thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at array_diff: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php